# What's the safest password type?

Tags: passwords, account-security

I've used Dashline (password manager) with random generated passwords, but I forgot the master password and there is no way to get it back. I read that password managers and random generated passwords aren't that safe as I thought they are. So what type of a password should I have that is the safest?

Comment: i don't know what you read, no citation, but random generated passwords are great, better than "battery horse stapler" these days...

Comment: You apparently have no idea what you are talking about. First of all the reference is "correct horse battery *staple*", and that style of *is* random, and with a sufficient number of words is just as secure as a password made of random characters: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase

Comment: @Ben: Ah, i knew it was something like that, i have trouble remembering other people's passwords... My point is that using 4 plain dictionary words isn't great as it was 10 years ago, when we were defending against naive fast hashing guesses instead of KDFs.

Answer (score 2):

Losing a password manager's master password usually isn't too catastrophic, just a huge hassle. You can still reset those lost passwords so long as you have your email account and any other relevant form of authentication.

For human-memorable passwords (your password manager's master password, stuff you have to type into anywhere that password managers aren't available such as disk encryption and login, accounts you want to ensure you retain access to like email), [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html)-style passphrases are still the best that I'm aware of. You want more than four words unless you're pulling from an *extremely* large corpus - the 7776 words of the official Diceware site is a bit short to be safe at only four words long (51.7 bits of entropy, assuming the attacker knows you use that method) - but even just four Diceware words will be much stronger than almost any human-generated password/passphrase. A stronger passphrase can be made using more words (even going just to 5 will be sufficient to resist modern hardware assuming a slow hash is used, but going to 6 or more will be very expensive to break even with a fast hash). A larger word list (corpus) will also help, though less effectively (doubling the number of words in the passphrase doubles the entropy; doubling the number of words in the corpus adds only one bit of entropy per word).

For anything that your password manager will autofill for you, let it generate a nice strong random password. It'll be stronger than a Diceware-style passphrase of reasonable length; there are more than 100 printable characters on a standard US keyboard, and just 16 random characters from a set of 100 is 10^32 possibilities (106.3 bits of entropy) but there's no need to stop at 16. It'll be a pain if you ever have to type it manually, but even somebody shoulder-surfing you isn't likely to successfully memorize it like they could with a Diceware passphrase.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention passwords for what purpose you mean.

**Login passwords**

Many web sites and applications *count failed login attempts* lock user account after 3 - 5 login failures. Some web sites and applications use *2-factor authentication*. Some use *additional factors* like IP range, browser meta info, device info.

In such cases it is *not necessary* to have long and complex passwords. For instance, even if password length is only 10 and even if it only contains lower case letters without uppercase, without digits, without special characters, it can still be safe. Example? Look at Google Mail. Their password policy allows relatively simple passwords, wheres they employ other methods (IP range, browser and device meta info) and the login is very secure.

**Cryptographic passwords**

If you mean passwords for cryptographic purposes like encryption or digital signature, then the rules differ essentially from the login rules. An attacker has access to the target files and can try as many passwords as he wants. That's why the passwords have to be complex so that they provide at least 80 bits entropy.

To **password types**: Actually important is how many bits entropy they have. It doesn't matter if it is a randomly generated set of characters or randomly generated sequence of Diceware words. Many password managers show the entropy of the generated password. Just make sure the entropy is at least 80 bits.

- If you want that your password consists only of lower case letters without digits and special characters, you need 17 characters to get 80 bits entropy.
- If you want to use lower and upper case letters with digits and some special characters, then 13 such characters will give you 80 bits entropy.
- If you prefer Diceware style passwords, 6 words Diceware password will give you 77 bits entropy (better use 7 words which is 90 bits).

No password type is secure or insecure per se. Just make sure the entropy is big enough.

Comment: Google Mail is a weird example. I can't think of a website off the top of my head that has more than 8 characters minimum. On the other hand, one can still find websites where 8 characters is the upper limit, not the lower (e.g. some banks are noted here: https://dev.to/mitchpommers/what-would-it-take-to-increase-the-password-max-length-limit-23lj ).